# Check if a Relying Party Trust/Claims Provider Trust is already configured by using the metadata entityID

Tags: windows-server-2012, adfs

How can I check if a **Relying Party Trust** and/or a **Claims Provider Trust** is already configured in **ADFS** according with its metadata **entityID**?

I checked about the **[Get-ADFSClaimsProviderTrust](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee892320.aspx)** cmdlet, but according to the documentation, it works by using the symbolic name and the identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed. So specify the "**-Identifier** *EntityID*" and it will show you if it exists :-).
Without ID it will show all existing parties. Same for Get-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust.
Or what else is the question?